# Поиск и удаление строки по запросу

Tags: mysql, sql

К примеру у меня имеется строка строка такого вида: **Информатика пг 1,** или **Математика пг 2**. Как можно сделать так, чтобы по запросу оставалось только математика, или только информатика? Объяснил как можно понятнее.

Comment: Опишите проблему подробнее. Удаление строки таблицы происходит через [DELETE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) (`DELETE FROM... WHERE...`), удаление строки/слова в поле строки таблицы можно сделать через [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) (`UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE...`). Уточните что именно вас интересует и как вы представляете это удаление.

Comment: Подозреваю что в некотором поле таблицы у вас строки с пробелами и вам нужно выбирать оттуда данные до первого пробела?

Comment: Дело в том что могут встречаться такие строки к примеру как: Дискретная математика. В этом случае останется только слова дискретная.

Comment: В вашей постановке вопроса всё решается элементарно: `UPDATE таблица SET поле = "математика" WHERE поле LIKE "%математика%"`. Вы именно этого хотите?

Comment: Да, только там не только математика, а другие предметы тоже.

Comment: sorry, тупанул.

Comment: А если там 100 уникальных значений(предметов), мне нужно 100 раз указать получается.. OR OR OR

Comment: Честно, все равно не понятно. Вы говорите, что удалять надо по запросу (т.е. "надо удалить математику"), а пример приводите, когда надо математику оставить. Если по первому варианту ("удалить математику"), то можно попробовать [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace), либо поизвращаться через `CONCAT/LOCATE/SUBSTR`. Если по второму варианту - можно попробовать тупо `UPDATE ... SET f_field = 'Информатика' WHERE f_field LIKE '%Информатика%'`

Comment: Нужно просто строку "очистить" от ненужных присвоений. В моем примере необходимо в строке, "Математика пг 1", избавится от пг 1, и оставить только чистое значение "Математика"

Comment: Поскольку mysql не знает что лишнее, а что нет, придется в общем случае делать как я показал: `SET f_field = 'Информатика' WHERE f_field LIKE '%Информатика%'` и так для каждого предмета. Если можно выделить какую-то закономерность (например, первое слово всегда не лишнее, а остальные всегда лишние), тогда через `CONCAT/LOCATE/SUBSTR` можно будет оставить только первое слово.

Comment: Варианты такие: 1. описать реальную задачу. 2. придумать алгоритм что на что надо менять, а не заставлять гадать других участников. 3. если изменение однократное, то тупо снять дамп таблицы, в блокноте пройти и поудалять лишнее, проапдейтить таблицу, не морочить людям голову.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это работа за автора

Comment: @VenZell Если бы мне было нужно чтоб все сделали за меня, я бы подробно расписал: таблицы, запросы, результат запроса. Но я просто спросил. Выложил бы это все на sqlfiddle. Благо, мне помог lDrakonl который действительно сделал все за меня, хотя я не ожидал что мне так здесь помогут.

Comment: Если не знаете чем мне помочь, почему бы просто не пройти мимо, и обойтись без пустой болтовни. Без вот этих минусов, голосований. Просто пройти мимо. Человек который захочет, поможет(lDrakonl), а не будет пустословить, В итоге вопрос заморожен, но результат все равно получен. А вы, своими безумственными дейстиями, создали здесь такой переполох. и оказался виновен я, что якобы вы не поняли вопроса. Ну не поняли, проигноруйте просто. Зачем так поступать? Вопрос в итоге все равно решен, благодаря lDrakonl. Извините, но накипело..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Судя по примерам и комментариям у вас там список предметов и групп. Похоже на то, что группы выглядят так `ПГ 1, ПГ 2...ПГ 5`. Возможно есть и другие группы.
Если речь идет об 1 факультете, то скорее всего список групп у вас не большой и их можно просто перечислить.
Вопрос я понял как "В базе лежат строчки вида Информатика пг 1, или Математика пг. Запросом получать только Информатика или Математика."
Тогда можно попробовать как то так:

```
case when name like '%пг%' then substr(name,1,instr(name, 'пг')-2)
     when name like '%пм%' then substr(name,1,instr(name, 'пм')-2)
else name end name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/487cd/11

Comment: Совершенно правильно! Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Вот ведь любопытно. Господа минусующие бы комментировали, чем плох ответ. Я в следующий раз смог бы лучше ответить. А так не понятно, в чем проблема.

Comment: мой минус был за угадывание. за решение следствия какой-то другой проблемы. за решение, основанное на анализе мусора и необходимости перечисления всех мусорных комбинаций, а не полезных данных. и вообще какой вопрос (-6), такой ответ (+1/-2).

Comment: @YuraIvanov по правде не очень понял, а что не так. Я согласен, что вопрос задан плохо. Но данных вполне хватает, чтобы понять, что автор спрашивает. Когда я регистрировался тут, я читал трогательную речь о решении конкретных проблема, а не обсуждении реализаций и идеологий. В стиле вопрос-ответ. Так поясните, что не так с моим ответом. Если можно по пунктам. Я учту при следующих ответах

Comment: Ссылки по теме http://xyproblem.info/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem
на русском тоже есть если что. \ Во втором ответе (правда он должен быть комментарием) содержится здравое зерно - такой задачи возникать не должно. Следовательно и решая ее за ТС, вы поощряете и автора, и других участников и гуглящих пользоваться костылями.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, я понимаю о чем Вы. Но это проблема постановки вопроса, а не ответа. Я же прошу пояснить все же проблему ответа. Вопрос заминусован, возможно справедливо. Но это никак не объясняет, что не так с ответом. Ответ не решает поставленную задачу? Ответ вводит автора в заблуждение? Вроде как нет. Возможно ТЗ автора вопроса таково, что по другому решать не получается. Проблема XY - это проблема вопроса. Но я спрашиваю, что не так с ответом? Если проблема только в том, что ответ помогает решить костыльное решение, то разве этот ответ плох? В общем так и не понял(

Comment: @lDrakonl я же написал что не так с ответом: показав решение, вы научили плохому. Взять несколько полей из разных таблиц, слепить их через concat или еще хуже через group_concat, потом через substr/instr разлепить получить сомнительный профит. Этот прием (или аналогичный) будет работать в виде ментального блока. ТС будет продолжать с упорством доказывая, что все отвечающие нихрена не понимают, лучше бы мимо проходили, пока либо не прочитает что-то по теме (в большинстве вопросов ТС об этом непрозрачно намекают), либо пока научрук не настучит по голове.

Answer (score -1):

**Разумеется,** надо изначально забивать в БД данные так, чтобы их не приходилось делить вручную. Если по незнанию база была спроектирована неправильно, то надо не городить костыли, а вручную отредактировать данные, приведя их в нормальную форму.

В частности, группы должны лежать в одной таблице, а предметы - в другой. То есть, не должно быть даже теоретической возможности того, что в одном поле будет присутствовать и название предмета, и название группы

Comment: Мне казалось, данный ресурс работает с идеей "Вопрос - Ответ" и старается уйти от рассуждений и критики логики, присущей многим форумам. Мне кажется, что каждый раз оставляя ответ на какой то вопрос вы по привычке минусуете все остальные ответы не оставляя комментариев. Хоть пишите, чем вам не нравятся другие ответы

Comment: Я не припоминаю чтоб из всех заданных мною вопросов, Вы дали конкретный ответ. Вы отвечаете в каждой моей теме, но Ваш извините КПД, нулевой. Тем более вы иногда без на то причины, отвергаете все предложенные ответы других участников, которые предлагают конкретные варианты решений(в итоге они оказываются правильными), а не подвергают меня критике. Можно ведь пройти мимо, как я писал выше. Я не сомневаюсь в ваших знаниях sql, возможно Вы отличный специалист, но в данном случае применить я их не могу.